# Cannot observe LiveData from parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I created an abstract GlobalActivity extending `AppCompatActivity` and a GlobalViewModel extending `ViewModel`, in order to have some `LiveData` always ready to show `Dialog` messages and `Toast` messages, as well as displaying and hiding a `ProgressBar`. Problem is that the LoginActivity is not observing the LiveData object I mentioned above, so is not reacting to changes nor calls. Here is my code:

GlobalActivity:

```
public abstract class GlobalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected GlobalViewModel mGlobalViewModel = new GlobalViewModel();
private Consumer<Throwable> errorHandler = throwable -> {
    Timber.e(throwable);
    DialogUtils.showOneButtonDialog(this, R.string.unexpected_error, null);
};

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(this.errorHandler);

    setUpBasicViewModel();
    mGlobalViewModel.getDialogMessage().observe(this, mssg -> DialogUtils.showOneButtonDialog(GlobalActivity.this, mssg, null));
    mGlobalViewModel.getToastMessage().observe(this, mssg -> DialogUtils.showMessage(mssg));
    mGlobalViewModel.getIsLoading().observe(this, bool -> setLoadingState(bool));
}

public abstract void setLoadingState(boolean bool);
public abstract void setUpBasicViewModel();
}
```

GlobalViewModel:

```
public class GlobalViewModel extends ViewModel {

protected MutableLiveData<String> dialogMessage = new MutableLiveData<>();
protected MutableLiveData<String> toastMessage = new MutableLiveData<>();
protected SingleLiveEvent<Boolean> isLoading = new SingleLiveEvent<>();

public GlobalViewModel(){}

public MutableLiveData<String> getDialogMessage() {
    return dialogMessage;
}

public MutableLiveData<String> getToastMessage() {
    return toastMessage;
}

public SingleLiveEvent<Boolean> getIsLoading() {
    return isLoading;
}
```

}

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends GlobalActivity {

private LoginViewModel mLoginViewModel;
private ActivityLoginBinding mDataBinding;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLoginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new LoginViewModelFactory()).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    mDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
    mDataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    mDataBinding.setViewModel(mLoginViewModel);
}

@Override
public void setLoadingState(boolean bool) {
    mDataBinding.progressBar.setVisibility(mDataBinding.progressBar.isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void setUpBasicViewModel() {
    mGlobalViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GlobalViewModel.class);
}
...
}
```

Comment: why not just use the single activity pattern and make use of a single activity with fragments, seems like less of an issue than this

Comment: I'll need to use several activities

Comment: So just to clarify, if you call `mGlobalViewModel.getDialogMessage().value = "..."` as the last statement in `GlobalActivity.onCreate()` then your observer doesn't trigger?

Comment: exactly @HenryTwist